# Test class with different scenarios for trigger helper

Tags: trigger, unit-test, after-trigger, helper

I have 100% coverage, but I still haven't scenarios for check. How to write good and bad scenarios for test class?

This is my helper:

```
public with sharing class JobHelper {

public static List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

public static void afterInsert(List<Job__c> newList) {

    for(Job__c job : newList){ 
        if(job.Stage__c == 'Closed'){
            createTask(job.OwnerId, 'Closed');
        }
        if(job.Stage__c == 'Open'){
            createTask(job.OwnerId, 'Open');
        }
    }
    insertTask(newList);
}

public static void afterUpdate(List<Job__c> newList, Map<ID, Job__c> oldMap) {

    for(Job__c job : newList){ 
        if(job.Stage__c == 'Closed' && oldMap.get(job.Id).Stage__c != 'Closed'){
            createTask(job.OwnerId, 'Closed');
        }
        if(job.Stage__c == 'Open' && oldMap.get(job.Id).Stage__c != 'Open'){
            createTask(job.OwnerId, 'Open');
        }
    }
    insert taskList;
}

public static List<Task> createTask(Id ownId, String subj){
    taskList.add(new Task(OwnerId = ownId, Subject = subj));
    return taskList;
}
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger JobTrigger on Job__c (after insert, after update) {

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
    JobHelper.afterInsert(Trigger.new);
}
else if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
    JobHelper.afterUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
}
}
```

My test-try:

```
@isTest
private class JobTest {


public static List<Job__c> jobList = new List<Jobn__c>();

static testMethod void createTaskTest(){

    Job__c job1 = new Job__c(
        Stage__c = 'Closed',
    );
    jobList.add(job1);

    Job__c job2 = new Job__c(
        Stage__c = 'Open',
    );
    jobList.add(job2);

    insert jobList;

    List<Task> taskListTest = new List<Task>();
    Task task1 = new Task(Subject = 'Closed');
    taskListTest.add(task1);

    Task task2 = new Task(Subject = 'Open');
    taskListTest.add(task2);

    insert taskListTest;

    JobHelper j = new JobHelper();
    //System.assert(taskListTest == j.taskList);
}
}
```

Comment: I would browse through https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm documentation and make sure to click 'Next' at the bottom to check out code examples. Test scenarios can vary wildly depending on what your code is actually doing, but ideally, you would like to cover at least a success and a failure scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                 What to Test in Apex
```

Salesforce recommends that you write tests for the following:-

**Single action**

Test to verify that a single record produces the correct, expected result.

**Bulk actions**

Any Apex code, whether a trigger, a class or an extension, may be invoked for 1 to 200 records. You must test not only the single record case, but the bulk cases as well.

**Positive behavior**

Test to verify that the expected behavior occurs through every expected permutation, that is, that the user filled out everything correctly and did not go past the limits.

**Negative behavior**

There are likely limits to your applications, such as not being able to add a future date, not being able to specify a negative amount, and so on. You must test for the negative case and verify that the error messages are correctly produced as well as for the positive, within the limits cases.

**Restricted user**

Test whether a user with restricted access to the sObjects used in your code sees the expected behavior. That is, whether they can run the code or receive error messages.

In your case, As I can see from your trigger helper:-

- You haven't written anything to handle the exception. You can add it and make changes in your test class accordingly.
- You haven't tested for the bulk uploads(Update and insert)
- you can run the test in different profile user context to see whether the class is obeying fLS, sharing rule, object permission or not.

Reference:-

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_what.htm
2. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro

Hope it helps you.